# Acumatica Numbering Sequence - cant default to the new symbol

Tags: acumatica

I've got a custom table storing serviceable components within fixed assets. The list is accessed using a grid on the AssetMaint screen.

I've set up an ID field to populate using a numbering sequence. I'm unsure how to set the default so this field populates with "<NEW>" by default, which is then updated by the numbering sequence when the component is saved.

It's sort of working, but there are a few issues. When I click the add button, the ID field is blank, but when I click add again, it populates with the "<NEW>" symbol. However if I add a third record before hitting save, the second record does not populate with "<NEW>". The second record is also not saved, unless I manually put "<NEW>" in the ID field.

This is part of the DAC for the component table:

```
 [Serializable]
public class FAServiceComponent : IBqlTable
{
    #region AssetID
    public abstract class assetID : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(FixedAsset.assetID), DefaultForUpdate = false)]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<FixedAsset, Where<FixedAsset.assetID, Equal<Current<FAServiceComponent.assetID>>>>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Asset ID", Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
    public virtual int? AssetID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region serviceComponentID
    public abstract class serviceComponentID : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(30, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Component ID")]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search2<Numbering.newSymbol, 
        InnerJoin<FixedAsset, On<FixedAssetExt.usrServiceComponentNumberingSeq, Equal<Numbering.numberingID>, And<FixedAsset.assetID, Equal<Current<FixedAsset.classID>>>>>>))]
    [Numbering]
    public virtual string ServiceComponentID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region serviceComponentDescription
    public abstract class description : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public class NumberingAttribute : AutoNumberAttribute
    {
        public NumberingAttribute(): 
            base(typeof(Search<FixedAssetExt.usrServiceComponentNumberingSeq, Where<FixedAsset.assetID, Equal<Current<FixedAsset.classID>>>>), 
                 typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate)) {; }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the page do you have InitNewRow="true"? (Goes inside the PXGrid something like this... <Mode InitNewRow="true" ></Mode> )

Comment: ~Yeah I've got that enabled~

I do now. I'd enabled it after I made this post. The <new> populates when the record is created now, but I'd still got the issue where it doesn't populate on the second record if I don't save between records.

Comment: @Brendan InitNewRow=True is what I was missing, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out T200 course available at [Acumatica Open University](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t200-acumatica-framework-fundamentals/). Part 4 Lesson 8 show you how to use the AutoNumberAttribute.

I would first suggest to remove the following code, as it is not required to make the < New > symbol work.

```cs
[PXDefault(typeof(Search2<Numbering.newSymbol, 
        InnerJoin<FixedAsset, On<FixedAssetExt.usrServiceComponentNumberingSeq, Equal<Numbering.numberingID>, And<FixedAsset.assetID, Equal<Current<FixedAsset.classID>>>>>>))]
```

You should have a setup screen where you choose the numbering sequence you want to use. As an example, the Sales Orders Preferences screen (SO101000) has the Shipment Numbering Sequence field, bound to `SOSetup.ShipmentNumberingID`.

In your graph, make sure you have the setup data view, something like `public PXSetup<Setup> AutoNumSetup;`. The PXSetup DAC should match with your setup screen, e.g. `PXSetup<SOSetup> ShipmentSetup`

In your DAC, the numbered field should have the AutoNumberAttribute referencing the setup table. e.g.

```cs
[AutoNumber(typeof(SOSetup.ShipmentNumberingID), typeof(SOShipment.shipDate))]
```

In Numbering Sequence screen (CS201010), make sure that **Manual Numbering** is unchecked and that you have a **New Number Symbol** set for the numbering sequence you are using.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the [PXDefault] attribute. I had defined the numbering id inside a FixedAsset user field. I've swapped this for your method as its a bit simpler. The field populates quicker with the [PXDefault] bit cleaned up. I've still got the issue with only the first <NEW> populating. If I add a second record without saving the first, the second <NEW> doesn't populate.